# Identifying Selection Sort vs Insertion Sort

Tags: arrays, sorting

I've read multiple articles on how Selection Sort and Insertion sort work, and believe I understand their implementations. Selection sort iterates over the unsorted numbers in the inner loop, whereas insertion sort iterates over the sorted numbers in the inner loop. From what I understand, that's basically the only difference.

My question lies in the scenario where you're posed an input array, lets say it's this one:

```
Input Array: 30, 70, 40, 60, 50
```

Now, you're given a further list where the iterations are shown:

```
30, 70, 40, 60, 50
30, 40, 70, 60, 50
30, 40, 50, 60, 70
30, 40, 50, 60, 70
```

How is one meant to identify whether Insertion Sort or Selection sort has been used based PURELY on this? There is no code given, nor are we required to write any code. We are only required to choose which algorithm has been used from a multiple choice list. (Yes, both appear in the list).

To be clear, this is not an assignment question. However, this *is* assisting  me with revision for an exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with the lecturer via email, I have a solution to this question. This is indeed a Selection Sort, with the elements therefore being swapped in place. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Now, for the explanation:

Selection Sort:

```
Input Array: 30, 70, 40, 60, 50
```

Sorting:

```
30, 70, 40, 60, 50 // 30 is already sorted.
30, 40, 70, 60, 50 // Swap 40 and 70.
30, 40, 50, 60, 70 // Swap 70 and 50.
30, 40, 50, 60, 70 // Array is sorted.
```

Here's what it looks like for an insertion sort:

```
Input Array: 30, 70, 40, 60, 50
```

Sorting:

```
30, 70, 40, 60, 50 // 30 is inserted.
30, 70, 40, 60, 50 // 70 is inserted.
30, 40, 70, 60, 50 // 40 is inserted.
30, 40, 60, 70, 50 // 60 is inserted.
30, 40, 50, 60, 70 // 50 is inserted. 
Array is now sorted.
```

I hope this helps anybody else that may come across a similar problem in the future while undertaking an algorithms course at college or university.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what happens in each of the algorithms: selection sort always selects the minimum of the unsorted elements and adds it to the end of the sorted elements; insertion sort always takes the first of the unsorted elements and inserts it in the correct place in the sorted list.

Selection sort:

```
Sorted         | Unsorted
               | 30 70 40 60 50
30             | 70 40 60 50    # selects 30, the minimum unsorted element
30 40          | 70 60 50       # selects 40
30 40 50       | 70 60          # selects 50
30 40 50 60    | 70             # selects 60
30 40 50 60 70 |                # selects 70
```

Insertion sort:

```
Sorted         | Unsorted
               | 30 70 40 60 50
30             | 70 40 60 50    # inserts 30, the first unsorted element
30 70          | 40 60 50       # inserts 70
30 40 70       | 60 50          # inserts 40
30 40 60 70    | 50             # inserts 60
30 40 50 60 70 |                # inserts 50
```

The arrays listed in each iteration would be the concatenation of the sorted  and unsorted portions of the array. It looks like these iterations show neither selection sort nor insertion sort.

Comment: According to the answers, this is a selection sort. Though I am confirming with the lecturer that this is accurate.

Comment: Also, it is relevant to point out that this is being sorted in place. Which means there's no unsorted array, it's all being done inside the one array. I believe this is where I may have gone astray. According to the gif on selection sort on wikipedia, elements are swapped.